# Javafx center shape on screen inside Group

Tags: java, javafx

I made a sketch with the behavior I'm trying to get.

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4pJf.png)

So I want to display a rectangle in the middle of the screen and a triangle that covers part of the rectangle. The problem is, when I use a `Stackpane`the rectangle is centered but the triangle as well and I can't move it to the bottom right position. When I use a `Group`it is not centered. Is there any way to get my intended behavior?

Comment: Maybe you should add some other container in StackPane which can allow you to move that rectangle anywhere you want?

Comment: Any suggestion which one to use?

Comment: Create a stackpane inside the stackpane you already have. The length and width of this new stackpane should be the sides of the rectangle you are going to add to it. Add the rectangle. The rectangle constrants should be zero top, bottom, left, and right. <- Meaning, make the rectangle fill this stackpane. Now add the triangle to the new stackpane like mentioned below.

Comment: How can I create a `StackPane` and specify the length and width of it?

Answer (score 0):

Set alignment of your triangle. Use static `setAlignment(Node child, Pos value)` method:

```
StackPane.setAlignment(triangle, Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT)
```

Comment: That will not make the desired effect, because it display the triangle in the bottom right of the screen. Again, I want the rectangle to be displayed in the center of the screen and the triangle should cover the bottom right of the rectangle.

Comment: Then add rectangle and triangle to `StackPane`, use my answer and put that `StackPane` in the center of screen.

Comment: Do you mean to a additional `StackPane`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Additional `StackPane` only for rectangle and triangle.